# Как вставить в программу символ чтобы можно было вывести в консоли?

Tags: c#, char

Надо вставить личный символ в мою программу. Для этого я создаю символ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мы имеем Код E000, так вот как мне вставить в мою программу чтобы можно было вывести в консоли?

Comment: Не уверен, что без [замены всего шрифта](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20631634/12888024) это возможно.

Comment: Консоль не для графики. Либо вы используете стандартные шрифты, либо используете графическую оболочку программы.